# Available Membership Starter Kits / Membership NuGet Packages for ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, facebook-c#-sdk, nuget

I'm looking for a Membership starter kit / NuGet package for MVC3 to handle things like user management as well as Facebook Authentication and Twitter Authentication.

The Microsoft.Web.Helpers seems to have some Facebook and Twitter helpers, but I don't think it has exactly what I'm looking for.

There is a good MVC Membership Starter Kit available, but I believe it is for MVC2 and I think Facebook / Twitter support is likely outside of its scope...
https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit

I feel like this should exist at this point, and that I just can't find it.  So the question... Does anyone know of a NuGet package or starter kit for management of ASP.NET MVC3 membership and perhaps includes integrated Facebook and Twitter authentication out-of-box?

Answer (score 10):

The Microsoft.Web.Helpers are the only packages I know of that have FaceBook and Twitter helpers. We don't currently have a Membership Starter Kit available for ASP.NET MVC 3 as a NuGet package.

But I think it would be great to have one and we'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks Phil, please keep me in the loop.  I think it would be a really useful and reusable piece.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it was just a matter of time to see NuGet packages appearing... these are the ones I saw today:

[SecurityGuard 1.0.51.583](https://nuget.org/packages/SecurityGuard) ( I just tried it and it's AWESOME! :D )

[image]

Here's the story about it: http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/tools/kahanu/securityguard-nuget-package-for-asp-net-membership

---

[MvcMembership 3.6.0](https://nuget.org/packages/MvcMembership)

---

[SimpleMembership.Mvc3 1.2](https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleMembership.Mvc3)

For more NuGet packages, try searching here: https://nuget.org/packages?q=membership

Comment: Thanks for these, hadn't seen SecurityGuard yet.  BTW I wrote up a comparison of Social Auth libraries a couple months back: http://blog.marcmezzacca.com/2012/03/social-authentication-for-net-a-library-comparison/